# Alternative to diag(X'*C*X) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, matlab-deployment

Consider an N x 1 vector x and an N x N matrix C. I would like to evaluate

```
 s = x'*C*x;
```

in matlab for many sampled of the vector x, e.g. consider M samples of x as an N x M matrix X; this can be done using

```
S = diag(X'*C*X);
```

but this is a poor solution as an M x M matrix is allocated in the process, and this breaks for M>1e5. Is there some matlab functionality which can suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the right matrix multiplication `C*X`, and then perform elementwise products, so that no unneeded operations are done:

```
S = sum(X.*(C*X),1)';
```

If your matrices are complex valued, you also need to conjugate:

```
S = sum(conj(X).*(C*X),1).';
```

Comment: Good idea! Much better than my approach

Answer (score 0):

A little [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)-ing and [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)-ing will do the trick. Note, however, that this requires an intermediate matrix of size `N*N`×`M`. This will be feasible (and quite fast) if `N` is small compared to `M`. Otherwise you may need to resort to using loops.

```
T = reshape(bsxfun(@times, permute(conj(X), [1 3 2]), permute(X, [3 1 2])), [], M);
S = sum(bsxfun(@times, C(:), T), 1).';
```

Example:

```
M = 5;
N = 6;
C = rand(N,N) + 1j*rand(N,N);
X = rand(N,M) + 1j*rand(N,M);
T = reshape(bsxfun(@times, permute(conj(X), [1 3 2]), permute(X, [3 1 2])), [], M);
S = sum(bsxfun(@times, C(:), T), 1).';
S_check = diag(X'*C*X);
S./S_check % may not be exactly equal due to numerical accuracy
```

gives

```
>> S./S_check
ans =
  1.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
  1.000000000000000 - 0.000000000000000i
  1.000000000000000 - 0.000000000000000i
  1.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
  1.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
```